# WPF C# Updating Polyline points realtime from different UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Hello I'm creating polyline with dots(elipse) which will be updated by user mouse move after he clicked on dot, problem is that dot is moving which is good, but does not update source which is ObservableCollection

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="sampleWPF.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:l="clr-namespace:sampleWPF" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Green" MouseRightButtonDown="MainWindow_OnMouseRightButtonDown_">
<Window.Resources>
    <l:PointCollectionConverter x:Key="pointCollectionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" Background="Yellow" Width="300" Height="300" MouseMove="UIElement_OnMouseMove">
        <Polyline x:Name="polyline" Stroke="Black" Width="300" Height="300" Points="{Binding PointCollection, Converter={StaticResource pointCollectionConverter}}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PointCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/> <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Blue" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Some explanation:
MainWindow_OnMouseRightButtonDown_ stops selected elipse move.

UIElement_OnMouseMove moves elipse in canvas

UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown selects elipse which will be moved

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        PointCollection.Add(new Point(0, 0));
        PointCollection.Add(new Point(20, 20));
        PointCollection.Add(new Point(30, 30));
        PointCollection.Add(new Point(50, 50));
        PointCollection.Add(new Point(80, 80));
        PointCollection.Add(new Point(100, 100));
    }
    private ObservableCollection < Point > PointCollectionProperty {
        get;
        set;
    } = new ObservableCollection < Point > ();

    public ObservableCollection < Point > PointCollection {
        get => PointCollectionProperty;
        set {
            PointCollectionProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PointCollection));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string caller) {
        PropertyChanged ? .Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    Point point;
    private Point selectedPoint;
    bool activated = false;
    private Ellipse selectedEllipse;
    private ContentPresenter selectedContentPresenter;

    private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (sender is Ellipse es) {
            Mouse.Capture(es);
            selectedEllipse = es;
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(selectedEllipse);
            if (parent != null) {
                selectedContentPresenter = parent as ContentPresenter;
            }

            point = Mouse.GetPosition(selectedContentPresenter);

            if (PointCollection.Any(t => t.X == Canvas.GetLeft(selectedContentPresenter) && t.Y == Canvas.GetTop(selectedContentPresenter))) {
                Debug.WriteLine("found");
                selectedPoint = PointCollection.FirstOrDefault(t =>
                    t.X == Canvas.GetLeft(selectedContentPresenter) && t.Y == Canvas.GetTop(selectedContentPresenter));
            } else {
                selectedPoint = new Point();
                Debug.WriteLine("not found");
            }

            activated = true;

        }

    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (selectedContentPresenter != null) {
            if (activated) {

                double top = Canvas.GetTop(selectedContentPresenter) + Mouse.GetPosition(selectedContentPresenter).Y + point.Y;
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedContentPresenter) + Mouse.GetPosition(selectedContentPresenter).X + point.X;

                Canvas.SetTop(selectedContentPresenter, top);

                Canvas.SetLeft(selectedContentPresenter, left);
                selectedPoint.X = left;
                selectedPoint.Y = top;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PointCollection));

            }
        }

    }

    private void MainWindow_OnMouseRightButtonDown_(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        foreach(Point child in PointCollection) {
            Debug.WriteLine(child.X + " " + child.Y);// shows original values from public MainWindow()
        }
        Mouse.Capture(null);
        activated = false;
        selectedEllipse = null;
        selectedContentPresenter = null;
    }
}
 public class PointCollectionConverter: IValueConverter {
 Debug.WriteLine("Called");
 public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
     if (value.GetType() == typeof(ObservableCollection < Point > ) && targetType == typeof(PointCollection)) {
         var pointCollection = new PointCollection();
         foreach(var point in value as ObservableCollection < Point > ) pointCollection.Add(point);
         return pointCollection;
     }

     return null;

 }

 public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
     return null;
 }
 }
```

What I'm missing here since elipse does move but polyline stays untouched

Edit: added Debug.WriteLine to show if its working, but  spams debug but collection stays still the same

[Image proving that it breaks after mouse move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itED9.png)

Comment: is your converter (`pointCollectionConverter`) beeing called? if not your propertyChanged event never boubbles up

Comment: also try using a DepencyProperty of type 'System.Windows.Media.PointCollection' instead of the ObservableCollection this will get rid of your converter and might fix your issue alltogether

Comment: @DenisSchaf its it calls pointCollectionConverter

Comment: no..i want to know if the converter is triggered... set a breakpoint in there and see if it gets hit if you change the observable collection

Comment: @DenisSchaf I added image that shows it breaks after mouse move

Comment: use the visualtree to debug if the binding is still working correctly
i just testet, a polyline will definitly liveupdate its shape if you change its source points

Comment: This works:
            <TextBox Name="pointy">0,0 100,100 200,100 300,60 100,00</TextBox>
            <Polyline Points="{Binding ElementName=pointy, Path=Text}"/>
so you will also be able to use any dependecy property different than text